# Can't Parse CSV in Plone 4

Tags: plone

I am trying to batch load some dummy content from a CSV file into a development site to do some testing.  I'm using Plone 4.0.1, with Python 2.6.5, on a Mac OS X 10.6.6.

1) I thought I would create a quick script that would iterate through a CSV file and then create some of my custom contenttypes: (Similar to http://plone.org/documentation/kb/batch-adding-users).  In Plone 3, I had been able to parse CSV files in this fasion.

However, I got an AttributeError on split.  I'm copying from my ipython (ipzope) testing:

```
>>> portal
<PloneSite at /Plone>
>>> portal['Scripts']['dummydata.csv']
<File at /Plone/Scripts/dummydata.csv>
>>> dummy = portal['Scripts']['dummydata.csv']
>>> dummy
<File at /Plone/Scripts/dummydata.csv>
>>> dummy.data.split('\n')
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: split

>>> dummy.split('\n')                                               
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: split
```

2) Ultimately, I'd like to use csv from the standard library, which also did not work.

```
>>> import csv
>>> csv
<module 'csv' from '/Applications/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/csv.pyc'>
>>> spamReader = csv.reader(dummy, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument 1 must be an iterator

>>> spamReader = csv.reader(dummy.data, delimiter=',', quotechar='"') 
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument 1 must be an iterator
```

Any ideas?

Best,
Patrick

Comment: Yup, this is nasty. :-) As Ross says, don't import CSV from a File object in Plone. Import CSV from a file on the file system using Python, then do something with it in Plone.

Comment: @waldopat: Please don't forget to upvote and accept answers as a gesture of appreciation, that people were investing time and thoughts to help you further, thanks :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> csv_io = StringIO(dummy.data)
>>> csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_io, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
>>> for i in csv_reader: print i
['a','b','c']
['d','e','f']
...
```

More info about python and csv can be found here: http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Bye,
Giacomo

Comment: Hi Giacomo, this works!  I am using UTF-8 info and using the UnicodeReader from the Python documentation for csv breaks on codec.  codecs.getreader('utf-8')(dummy.data) brings me the <OFS.Image.Pdata object at 0x1096e1410>, which is not iterable.  Will need to think about this one.

Comment: Actually this works on UTF-8 as well.  I set a title with UTF-8 characters, including ©, and it set just fine.  I completely avoided the UnicodeReader and just iterated through the csv_reader as above.  Worked like a charm.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The core problem here is relying on the internals of the File object.  For example, the File implementation may use a linked data structure where the top level "File.data" object itself has a link to a "File.data.data" object to break up the objects in the database allowing reading part of the file without loading the whole thing from the database.  In this case, you'd only get part of the file data accessing the attribute directly.  But this is just an example of the kind of gotchas you can run into when relying on internals.

Instead, access the file contents using an interface explicitly supported by the File object.  Assuming the File object is a OFS.Image.File instance, the only thing I see it supporting is str().  So your best bet if your only option is to use a OFS.Image.File instance in the ZODB is to do str(dummy).split('\n').

That said, this will likely be very memory intensive for large files.  You'd be much better off loading your CSV from a file on the filesystem which the Python CSV module will access efficiently without loading it all into memory.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  You're right.  I think I'm better off using the file system, which works just fine, since I will be using some large files.  However, I'm still puzzled why I could follow the Batch Adding Users technique in Plone 3 and I cannot in Plone 4.

Comment: Look for changes in the csv module from Python 2.4 (Plone 3) to Python 2.6 (Plone 4). The error is fairly self explanatory, you are calling the function with an unexpected argument (a File obj) when it expects an iterator.